# Retrieving text from an Hwnd and releasing the allocated memory space

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I am new to VB.Net. I came from vb6 and VBA so I'm still learning. I am trying to clear the memory space for when I retrieve text using my GetWinTxt() function. I am not sure if I am properly releasing the memory space or not. I have researched MSDN and a multitude of other sites including this one trying to learn about this and I find it somewhat confusing. This function will be used a lot and i don't want a memory leak. It seems to be working fine as there isn't any error codes but can someone with more knowledge please tell me if I'm doing this right? Also should I be using Marshal.DestroyStructure() before I use Marshal.FreeHGlobal()? And if so how would I use that in my code below?

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Friend Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
Friend Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim Hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, "Untitled - Notepad") 'notepad parent win
    Dim Handle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", Nothing) 'notepad edit area
    MsgBox(Lf.GetWinTxt(Handle))'Lf is my class name
End Sub

Friend Function GetWinTxt(hwnd As IntPtr) As String
    Dim TextLen As Integer = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0) + 1
    Dim WinHandle As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(TextLen)
    Call SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, TextLen, WinHandle)
    Dim txt As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(WinHandle)
    GetWinTxt = txt
    Dim ByteString(TextLen) As Byte ' the next 3 lines are what i'm not sure if i'm doing it right or not
    Marshal.Copy(WinHandle, ByteString, 0, TextLen)
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(txt) 
End Function
```

**EDITED FINAL CODE:**

```
Public Function GetWinTxt(hwnd As IntPtr) As String
    Dim TextLen As IntPtr = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0) + 1
    Dim f As Integer = TextLen
    Winhandle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(f)
    Call SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, f, Winhandle)
    Dim txt As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Winhandle)
    Return txt
    Try
        Dim ByteString(f) As Byte
        Marshal.Copy(Winhandle, ByteString, 0, f)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Winhandle)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Much easier to do this using `StringBuilder` and having the library handle all the details of marshaling. Do yourself a favour and learn C# rather than VB.net since you'll find way more resources online to help you.

Comment: I'll look into StringBuilder thank you! I can't go to c# because 90% of everything is written in vb.net in my company.

Comment: At least you need to know enough C# to be able to read examples in C# and then translate. For instance in this case you can get example code to do this written in C#, and then translate that.

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/ is a good on-line converter.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured it out and it's working great. Although I couldn't get the StringBuilder function to work with retrieving the text as I tried multiple different ways to do it. I figured out a different method and that one is working great. I prefer to use the marshaling though.

Comment: Way more work doing it that way. But I guess you. Can just try stuff at random until you happen upon code that appears to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, unless you call method like `Marshal. StructureToPtr()`.

You should use the counterpart of whatever method you used to allocate it.
Marshal. Destroy Structure will free all substructures that specify unmanaged memory block points to. But you don't have any structure in it.

In addition, you call `Dim WinHandle As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(TextLen)` Allocates memory from the unmanaged memory of the process to `WinHandle`, then free anther one, `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(txt)`. This will cause memory leaks.
try to change it to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(WinHandle)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It seems to be working great now!